# React warning message "Assign arrow function to a variable"

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a layout using React.
I got message in VSCODE.

*src\components\Common\Header\index.jsx
Line 5:1:  Assign arrow function to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export*

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What do I need to fix my code?

Comment: save the reference to the arrow function in a variable: `const fn = () => { ... }` and then export it using the variable: `export default fn`. More details: [import/no-anonymous-default-export](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md)

Comment: Did you read the rule? https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your function to a variable like so

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Layout = () => { // Here
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Layout; // Then export it by default
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a name to the exported object, because unnamed object cannot be exported, please find below example for the same:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const routeLinks () => {
return (
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to='/login'>Login</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
)
}

export default routeLinks;
```